# Android & Anko SQLite: how to select and parse rows without knowing the columns?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, anko

I'd like to select all rows from a table and parse it **without knowing the columns** and avoid something like `parseList(classParser<MyClass>())`, which works well, when I know the expected structure.

The [MapRowParser](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite#parsing-query-results) looks promising, but I'm not able to get it done.

Following some **pseudocode** to make it more clear:

```
val rows = context.database.use {
    select("any_table").exec {        
        parseList(myParser<String, String>()) // key => value
    }.toList()
}

for (row in rows) {
    foreach (row as column => value) {
        // here we have the column and it's value 
        // without knowing the column name
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!